# Fixing java.lang.nullpointException

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

Hi there I am trying to create an array of records in java in which you have to enter 3 details, the name of a town, the population and the county in which is resides. Before then outputting all the data on a county which you have asked for. I was wondering if anyone could show me why a null.point.exception occurs if I enter the population of a town when does not occur when i enter another one.

```
import java.util.*;
public class CathedralTowns
{
public static String name;

String population;
String county;
public static int count = 0;
public static int continuation = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     int loop1 = 0;

    while (loop1 <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the town. ('no' to end)");
        String nameEntered = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the county in which the town resides. ('no' to end)");
        String countyEntered = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the population of the town. ('no' to end)");
        String populationEntered = input.nextLine();

        if (nameEntered.equals("no") || populationEntered.equals("no") || countyEntered.equals("no") ) {
            loop1 = 5; 
            System.out.println("Thank you for entering your county.");
            continuation = 1;
        }
        WorkingDemCathedrals(nameEntered, populationEntered, countyEntered); 
    }   

}

public static void WorkingDemCathedrals(String nameEntered, String populationEntered, String countyEntered) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    CathedralTowns[] allTowns = new CathedralTowns[50];
    allTowns[count] = new CathedralTowns();
    int loop2 = 0;
    int loop3 = 0;
    while (loop2 == 0){

        allTowns[count].name = nameEntered; 
        allTowns[count].population = populationEntered; //the error relates back to here according to bluej
        allTowns[count].county = countyEntered;
        if (continuation == 1) {
            loop2 = 1;
            System.out.println("please enter the name of a county for which you wish to know the details.");
            String countyOfChoice = input.nextLine();
            while (loop3 > 0){

                    if ((allTowns[loop3].county).equals(countyOfChoice)){
                        System.out.println(allTowns[loop3].name);
                        System.out.println(allTowns[loop3].population);
                        loop3 = -2;
                    }
                     loop3 = loop3 +1;   
            }
        }
        count = count + 1;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Exception? stack trace please...

Comment: Did you debug your code? Where does the exception occur? Please mark the line, line numbers won't help.

Comment: Btw, `while (loop3 > 0)` seems to be broken, since `loop3` is set to 0 and not changed otherwise outside that loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements in an `Object` array are `null` by default. Initialialise the elements prior to attempting to access them

```
for (int i=0; i < allTowns.length; i++) {
    allTowns[i] = new CathedralTowns();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This lines is very suspicious

```
allTowns[count] = new CathedralTowns();
```

You allocate only one object in the array while you have a line before allocated an array of the length 50.

```
CathedralTowns[] allTowns = new CathedralTowns[50];
```

Not to mention that it is prone to `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `count` is equal or more that `50`

Then you start to loop and increment `count` and that's where it happens!

your should loop over the entire array and allocate an object in each slot.

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException occurs at "population" and not at "name" is because the "name" field is static, whereas the "population" is non-static.

Also the allocation of the array of CathedralTowns has to be done as per the first answer.

The `while (loop2 == 0)` could end up in a infinite loop. There is no end condition for this while loop, if the user wants to enter details of more than one county.